# Getting 2 divs aligned besides each other with margin between them in responsive only

Tags: css

I have some divs that I want aligned below each other in small resolutions (mobile) and 2 by 2 besides each other in bigger resolutions (tablet and desktop).

They are generated like this:

```
<div id="container">

<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>

</div>
```

And the CSS is:

```
#container{
  margin: 0 20px;
  background-color:#ececec;
}
.card{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #c4c4c4;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {

    .card{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height:100px;
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
    margin:5px;
    border:1px solid #c4c4c4;
  }

}

}
```

Here's a fiddle of how close I got: https://jsfiddle.net/dncjhzwg/

In mobile view, everything works fine. But as soon as I increase the window above 767 pixels, they are *almost* correctly displayed. The problem is I can't get the margins to work.

I need there to be NO margins on the left and right of each of them and 10px margin in the middle. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more valid approach would be to use either grid or flexbox

**Grid**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 20px;
  background-color: #ececec;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  #container {
    grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Flexbox**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 20px;
  background-color: #ececec;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  #container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content:space-between;
  }

  .card {
    flex:0 1 auto;
    width: calc(50% - 5px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>

</div>
```

---

You could also do it with the approach you already have, but there are some quirks to overcome. Mainly the fact that since you use `inline-block` the whitespace between the `div` elements is taken into consideration so you need to alter your html to remove it. After that just set a `left-margin` on the *right-side* elements.

Demo at https://jsfiddle.net/kmngh2qs/

And a general comment: you do not have to re-define the properties that remain the same between two media overlapping media queries. Only the properties that are changed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply and explanations. I will go with your flexbox suggestion and clean up the code. Thank you! :)